# MongoDB query to slow when using $or operator

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I'm trying to make this query to my collection `Audios`

```
    var querySlow = {
        "palabra": {
            $regex: "^" + keywords,
            "$options": "i"
        },
        $or: [{
            "_p_pais": {
                $in: interested_accents
            }
        }, {
            "languageCodeTatoeba": {
                $in: interested_accents_tatoeba
            }
        }]
    }; // takes 20 seconds
```

This is actually **really really slow** but if I remove any of the `$or`, it is **very very fast**, for example:

```
    var queryFast1 = {
        "palabra": {
            $regex: "^" + keywords,
            "$options": "i"
        },
        $or: [{
            "_p_pais": {
                $in: interested_accents
            }
        }]
    }; // takes less than 1 second
```

or this

```
    var queryFast2 = {
        "palabra": {
            $regex: "^" + keywords,
            "$options": "i"
        },
        $or: [{
            "languageCodeTatoeba": {
                $in: interested_accents_tatoeba
            }
        }]
    }; // takes less than 1 second
```

this is the `.explain()` of the slow query:

http://pastebin.com/nrhjB1wf

I actually don't know how to manage the indexes, should I create an index to this collection??

Comment: Can you post the `.explain()` of (either or both) the fast queries?

Answer (score 4):

There are some issues with your query and indexes:

**1. $or uses indexes differently**

MongoDB only uses one index for a query, with the exception of queries involving an `$or` clause. From the [Indexing Strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/) page:

> Generally, MongoDB only uses one index to fulfill most queries. However, each clause of an $or query may use a different index

Also from the [$or Clauses and Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-clauses-and-indexes) page:

> That is, for MongoDB to use indexes to evaluate an $or expression, all the clauses in the $or expression must be supported by indexes.

With regard to your query, you could try to rearrange the query to make the `$or` clause a top-level clause:

```
{$or: [
    {"palabra": {...}, "_p_pais": {...} },
    {"palabra": {...}, "languageCodeTatoeba": {...}}
]}
```

In this form, MongoDB can use two indexes:

- Compound index with `palabra` and `_p_pais` terms, and
- Compound index with `palabra` and `languageCodeTatoeba` terms

Please use `explain("executionStats")` to check if the indexes are used correctly. The key metric you want to minimize is the number of documents (`nReturned`) vs. total docs/keys examined. The closer the ratio is to 1, the more selective your query is, and the better the performance.

For example, if MongoDB has to examine 1000 docs (`totalDocsExamined: 1000`), but only return 10 document (`nReturned: 10`), then your query is not very selective (i.e. a ratio of 10/1000). Ideal queries would have a ratio close to or equal to 1, e.g. `nReturned: 10, totalDocsExamined: 10`, a ratio of 1 (10/10).

For more information regarding `explain()`, please see:

- [Explain Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/)
- [db.collection.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/)

**2. Too many indexes**

Having too many indexes could lead to:

- The query planner choosing a sub-optimal index, since it won't know which index to use since they all look the same.
- Relatively slow insert/update performance, since each insert/update to a field that is included in an index would also need to insert/update to the index as well.

From the explain result you posted, you have at least these indexes in the collection:

```
_p_pais_-1__p_user_-1__created_at_-1
languageCodeTatoeba_1_lowercase_1
languageCodeTatoeba_1
languageCodeTatoeba_-1
_p_pais_-1
_p_pais_1_languageCodeTatoeba_1
palabra_-1
palabra_1__created_at_-1
```

There are two issues with this set of indexes:

1. Among the indexes, some are redundant. For example, `languageCodeTatoeba_1` (an ascending index) and `languageCodeTatoeba_-1` (a descending index) are practically the same index. One of them can be removed without any effect on query performance.
2. A lot of indexes are prefix of another. For example, `palabra_-1` and `palabra_1__created_at_`. The `palabra_-1` index can be removed, since it is the prefix of the `palabra_1__created_at_` index. Please see the [Compound Index: Prefix](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes) page for more details.

From a cursory glance, you may be able to trim your index list to only contain these 4 indexes instead of 8:

```
_p_pais_-1__p_user_-1__created_at_-1
languageCodeTatoeba_1_lowercase_1
_p_pais_1_languageCodeTatoeba_1
palabra_1__created_at_-1
```

Please see the following links for more information regarding indexes:

- [Create Indexes to Support Your Queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/)
- [Indexing Strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/)

**3. Why removing one clause from the `$or` term speeds up the queries**

This is because the query

```
{"palabra": {...}, $or: [{"_p_pais": {...}}]}
```

is essentially the same as

```
{"palabra": {...}, "_p_pais": {...}}
```

Assuming you have a compound index such as `palabra_1__p_pais_1`, MongoDB would be able to use that index.

Similarly,

```
{"palabra": {...}, $or: [{"languageCodeTatoeba": {...}}]}
```

is essentially the same as

```
{"palabra": {...}, "languageCodeTatoeba": {...}}
```

This query could use the `_p_pais_1_languageCodeTatoeba_1` index, which you already have in your collection.

In short, those two queries are fast because you removed the `$or` clause, enabling MongoDB to use the correct index.