# Mongo $or query with ranges is doing an in-memory sort?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, indexing, mongodb-query

I'm running into a unique situation where one query seems to do an in-memory sort. Query 1 is the one that does the in-memory sort, while Query 2 is doing a merge sort correctly.

There are a few parts to the query, so I want to know which part is causing the query sort to be done in memory?

I do have a workaround, but I would like to know the reason behind this. They both have 2 input stages, so I'm not sure what is the cause.

Schema:

```
schema = {
    date: Date, // date that can change
    createTime: Date, // create time of document
    value: Number
}
```

Index:

```
schema.index({value: 1, createTime: -1, date: 1});
```

Query 1: I have $or at the top level to avoid using incorrect index: [MongoDB query to slow when using $or operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329806/mongodb-query-to-slow-when-using-or-operator/42475507#42475507)

```
db.getCollection('dates').find({
    $or: [
        {value: {$in: [1, 2]}, date: null},
        {value: {$in: [1, 2]}, date: {$gt: ISODate("2020-06-16T23:59:59.999Z")}}
   ]
}).sort({createTime:-1}).explain()
```

Query 1 plan: As you can see it does a sort in-memory. I'm not sure exactly why this is occurring.

```
{
    "stage" : "SUBPLAN",
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "createTime" : -1.0
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "OR",
                    "inputStages" : [ 
                        {
                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                            "filter" : {
                                "date" : {
                                    "$eq" : null
                                }
                            },
                            "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                    "value" : 1,
                                    "createTime" : -1,
                                    "date" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "value_1_createTime_-1_date_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                    "value" : [],
                                    "createTime" : [],
                                    "date" : []
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                    "value" : [ 
                                        "[1.0, 1.0]", 
                                        "[2.0, 2.0]"
                                    ],
                                    "createTime" : [ 
                                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                    ],
                                    "date" : [ 
                                        "[undefined, undefined]", 
                                        "[null, null]"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "value" : 1,
                                "createTime" : -1,
                                "date" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "value_1_createTime_-1_date_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "value" : [],
                                "createTime" : [],
                                "date" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "value" : [ 
                                    "[1.0, 1.0]", 
                                    "[2.0, 2.0]"
                                ],
                                "createTime" : [ 
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ],
                                "date" : [ 
                                    "(new Date(1592351999999), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Query 2:

```
db.getCollection('dates').find({
    value: {$in: [1, 2]},
    date: {$not: {$lte: ISODate("2020-06-16T23:59:59.999Z")}}
}).sort({createTime:-1}).explain()
```

Query 2 plan: The workaround query I used, which does a merge sort successfully.

```
{
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "SORT_MERGE",
        "sortPattern" : {
            "createTime" : -1.0
        },
        "inputStages" : [ 
            {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "value" : 1,
                    "createTime" : -1,
                    "date" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "value_1_createTime_-1_date_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "value" : [],
                    "createTime" : [],
                    "date" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "value" : [ 
                        "[1.0, 1.0]"
                    ],
                    "createTime" : [ 
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ],
                    "date" : [ 
                        "[MinKey, true]", 
                        "(new Date(1592351999999), MaxKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }, 
            {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "value" : 1,
                    "createTime" : -1,
                    "date" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "value_1_createTime_-1_date_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "value" : [],
                    "createTime" : [],
                    "date" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "value" : [ 
                        "[2.0, 2.0]"
                    ],
                    "createTime" : [ 
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ],
                    "date" : [ 
                        "[MinKey, true]", 
                        "(new Date(1592351999999), MaxKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the branches of `$or` could use an index, but then you still have two result sets and if you apply sort on top the database has to sort the results in memory. Seems reasonable that having sort over an $or operator would produce an in-memory sort.

Comment: But why can't it do a merge sort like the 2nd query? It also has 2 stages in the 2nd query. Is it that the individual stages are not sorted themselves, so they can't be merge?

Comment: What is a merge sort exactly?

Comment: I think merge sort is incorrect.

It is a sort merge, so merging 2 sorted arrays.

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying. If you are suggesting that MongoDB's behavior is in contradiction to its documentation (or other published claims), please reference the documentation that you think is being contradicted.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.

I am referring to SORT_MERGE stage in query 2 plan. I named in merge sort, but I think it means merging 2 sorted arrays not sorting with mergesort.

So I was just confused with the naming.

Comment: I think the differences is that query 1 plan does a FETCH stage that filters the index search, so it is not sorted in that case.

Comment: What is "it" in your last sentence?

Comment: The input stages:
query 1 input stages 0 index:

`"stage" : "FETCH",
"filter" : {
    "date" : {
        "$eq" : null
    }
},`

vs query 2 plan input stages 0 index:

`"stage" : "IXSCAN",
"keyPattern" : {
    "value" : 1,
    "createTime" : -1,
    "date" : 1
},`

Comment: Index scan produces documents in the index order. Since you are sorting on top of two conditions, the order of documents in the query is different from the order of documents in either index.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I think the reason query 1 is doing a fetch is because of the null equality: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18653